# aws-amplify forgot password function with react js sending SMS instead of email

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I build an app using aws-amplify that allows login with Cognito users. However, `Auth.forgotPassword` seems to be sending SMS to mobile device instead of EMAIL. How can I change the behavior such that it sends an email?

Here are related code:

```
Auth.forgotPassword(this.state.username)
  .then(data => this.setState({instruction: 'An email has been sent to your email with a temporary password.', usernameError: false, passwordError: false}))
  .catch(err => this.setState({instruction: err.message, usernameError: false, passwordError: false}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure what you need to verify when forgotPassword API is triggered in the AWS Cognito Console.

Amazon Cognito > Manage User Pool > Choose your pool > General Settings > MFA and verifications > [Which attributes do you want to verify?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQJSZ.png)

Also when you trigger the ForgotPassword API you get CodeDeliveryDetails Object in response

```
const result = await Auth.forgotPassword(username);
```

console.log(result);

```
CodeDeliveryDetails: {
    "AttributeName": "email",
    "DeliveryMedium": "EMAIL",
    "Destination": "n***@g***.com"
  }
```

From the result, you get on which medium the code has been delivered and accordingly notify the user in the app.